# Number format equivalent function in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-14

Trying to format the number as per the given format and culture.

Given:

```
-4059587.225000, --Value
'#,##0.00;(#,##0.00)' --Format
'en-US' --Culture
```

Will have many patterns, the given one is for example.

Expected output: `(4,059,587.23)`

In SQL Server we have `format()` function, what's the equivalent in PostgreSQL?

My try:

```
select to_char( -4059587.225000, '#,##0.00;(#,##0.00)' );
```

Error:

> multiple decimal points

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`to_char`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html):

```
SET lc_numeric = 'en_US';

SELECT translate(to_char(-4059587.225000, '9G999G999D99PRFM'), '<>', '()');

   translate    
════════════════
 (4,059,587.23)
(1 row)
```

[The documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-NUMERIC-TABLE) describes the available formats.

Comment: Can you please add link to find more patterns/format like `9G999G999D99PRFM`?

Comment: I have added links to the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
select 
concat( to_char( -4059587.225000, '#,##0.00;' ), to_char( -4059587.225000, '(#,##0.00)' ) );
```